# How Android handles usb keyboard/mouse event

Tags: android, linux-kernel, usb

Since Android uses volume daemon to deal with its uevent sent from kernel,

it does not handle the usb keyboard/mouse event since this types of subsystem are  not included by vold.

Hence, my question is how it actually handles usb keyboard/mouse event?

please provide your feedback.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it does not need to handle such events? Do you care about connecting keyboard to your smartphone?

Comment: Thanks. I am sure Android handles such events. How about if the Android powered device is a set-top box?

Comment: Modern Android phones with OTG capability will respond to the connection of a USB keyboard or mouse and use it appropriately, even displaying a mouse cursor.  What is not clear is if the "event" asked about here is connection/disconnection or keypress/movement.

Comment: Fair ) Don't know how to answer this. I would look for other components in Android similar to vold. Maybe they got something for input devices.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, Thanks for your reply. I want to know the basic flow about how Android responds to the connection of a USB keyboard or mouse.

Comment: @avd, yea, I will check those either. Thanks.

Comment: I've also posted another question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511900/android-powered-device-in-usb-host-mode. Please provide any feedback if you have any.