# Android powered device in USB host mode

Tags: android, linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver, usb-drive

Android has implemented the USB host mode in Android 3.1 and newer.

I've gone through documents in the following link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html

However, the information provided by Android official website is relatively too high level for me to understand the whole story.

I know that OTG is necessary to implement USB host mode.

I have some questions listed in the following:

1. How kernel deals with USB host mode? Does it need to configure any file?
2. How Android enters USB host mode in the low level ?
3. How Android switch between USB host mode and device mode?
4. To turn into this mode, is USB driver needed?

Please let me know if you have any idea about this.

Thanks

Comment: Usually it is triggered by grounding the ID pin on the connector, something usually accomplished by the micro-to-A adapter needed to connect an ordinary peripheral.  Typically there are no "drivers" beyond the basic ones (keyboard, mouse, etc) built into the kernel or available as modules - instead, arbitrary peripherals are exposed to userspace via a transfer-level API, not too different conceptually from handling a device from a desktop application via something like libusb.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, Thanks for your reply. Would you mind to answer this question in more detail in "Answer this question ". How about Android how to make itself turn into the USB host mode? Any document about this? Thanks!